# javascripts regular expression to keep span tag and remove other

Tags: javascript, regex

Can anyone provide me the regular expression in JavaScript for

Input:

```
<table><tr><td>hello<td/> <span class='xyz'>Hi all </span></tr></table>
```

Output:

```
hello<span class='xyz'>Hi all</span>
```

I can successfully use the following expression in Java but I don't know the equivalent regular expression in JavaScript.

```
String newValue = input.replaceAll("<(?!\\/?span)[^>]+>", "");
```

if i use following expression in js

> input.replace(/<(?!/?span)[^>]+>/g, "");

i am getting output as

```
 hello Hi all</span>
```

but i want

> `hello<span class='xyz'>Hi all</span>`

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regexes! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: *"I don't know the equivalent regular expression in JavaScript"* You could use the exact same expression.

Comment: The <center> cannot hold it is too late.

Answer (score 0):

This site may help you if you really want to get into this:
http://www.txt2re.com/index-php.php3

I already did first step for you:
http://www.txt2re.com/index-javascript.php3?s=%3Ctable%3E%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%3Ehello%3Ctd/%3E%20%3Cspan%20class=%27xyz%27%3EHi%20all%20%3C/span%3E%3C/tr%3E%3C/table%3E&-4&-19&-18&-11&-8&-1&-30&-25&-3&-7&-2

Comment: -1 This is a non-answer.